# rank$(R\otimes_R S)$ is the composition of $f^∗$ and rank$(P)$.

Tags: commutative-algebra, modules, projective-module

This is Weibel's K-book exercise 2.12

If $f : R →S $ is a homomorphism of commutative rings, there is a continuous map $f^*: Spec(S) → Spec(R)$ sending $p$ to $f^{-1}(p).$

If $P$ is a finitely
generated projective R-module, show that rank$(P\otimes_R S)$ is the composition
of $f^∗$ and rank$(P)$.

I don't know what's the mean of "composition of $f^∗$ and rank$(P)$."Since $P\otimes_R S$ can be viewed a $S(or\ R)$-module. I guess it means rank$(P\otimes_R S)$ calculated on some $q\in Spec S,$ then pulback to $R$. Right?

If you can tell me the correct meaning, I will thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

Citation from the exercises (Exercise 2.11): "$M$ is finitely generated,$M_p$ is free for every prime ideal $p$ of $R$, and $rank(M)$ is a continuous function on $Spec(R)$."

Hence

$$rank(-): Spec(R) \rightarrow \mathbb{Z}$$

is a continuous map.

Question: "If you can tell me the correct meaning, I will thank you very much."

Given a map $f:R \rightarrow S$ of commutative rings and corresponding map $f^*: Spec(S) \rightarrow Spec(R)$ of affine schemes,  you get according to Ex.2.11 a composed map

$$ rank(-) \circ f^*: Spec(S) \rightarrow \mathbb{Z}.$$

I have not done the exercise, but it seems to me Weibel wants you to prove the formula

$$F1.\text{   }rank(\tilde{P\otimes_R S})=rank(f^*(\tilde{P}))$$

where $\tilde{P}$ is the sheafification of $P$. Hence it seems to me you must do Exercise 2.11 in the book and verify formula F1.

Comment: Thank you very much. And the following is my thought. Since $S$ can be viewed as an $R$-module, so $P\otimes_R S$ is a finitely generated projective $S$-module(P is a finitely generated $R$-module). Let $p$ be a prime ideal of $S$, $q=f^{-1}(p)$ is a prime ideal of $R$. The rank of $P\otimes_R S$at $p$ is the free rank of $(P\otimes_R S)_p\cong (P\otimes_R S)\otimes_S S_p\cong (P\otimes _R R_q\otimes_{R_q})S_p\cong P_q\otimes_{R_q} S_p$. This may be the meaning of Weible.